# Pagination REST API, Multiple request, DML End problem

Tags: apex, rest-api, batch, dml

I was share 1 more question before in my profile, and i changed my apex code,

[My old question.](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/286806/how-can-i-use-pagination-to-in-get-request-rest-api)

Now i wrote my callout function in batch apex class, My problem is when i want to send second request for the get DML would be done, because of i getting DML END in logs, I guess i need the use iterable functions but am not sure

QueryLocator-> i guess i need the use iterable but how ?

```
         /**
         * Query process returning query here for the execute.
         * */
       global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext info){

            return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Main_Stock__c,ProductCode From Product2 LIMIT 10]);

       }
```

Execute part,

```
/**
     * Update, Upsert Or Insert Process.
     * */
   global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Product2> scope){
       Boolean LoopEnd = false;
       integer i = 0;
       while (LoopEnd == false) {
       i = i + 1;
       String Url = '************************?limit=200&page=';
       // HttpResponse Get the Method
       HttpResponse response = netsisResponse(Url,i);
       Map<String, Object> results = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
       Map<String,Object> data = (Map<String,Object>) results.get('data');
       List<Object>  Products = (List<Object>) data.get('productList');
       // Creating Keys For The Short Soql Command and Process

       Map<String,Object> ProductObject = new Map<String,Object>();
       Map<String,Object> Keys = new Map<String,Object>();
         for (Object prd : Products) {
            ProductObject = (Map<String, Object>) prd;
            String ProductCode = (String) ProductObject.get('ProductCode');
            Keys.put(ProductCode,ProductCode);
            }
       List<Product2> productScope = [SELECT Main_Stock__c,ProductCode From Product2 Where ProductCode IN: keys.keySet()];

       // Update products fields
        if (Products.Size() < 1) {
            LoopEnd = true;
        }
       else {
        for (Object prd : Products) {
            Map<String,Object> productapi = (Map<String, Object>) prd;
            for (Product2 product: productScope) {
                if (product.ProductCode == productapi.get('ProductCode')) {
                product.Main_Stock__c = (integer)productapi.get('MainStock'); 
                }
            }
        }  
           update productScope;  
    }           
}   
}
```

Callout-> HTTP response,

```
/**
    * HttpResponse request,
    **/
    public static HttpResponse netsisResponse(String Url, integer pageNumber) {
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setEndpoint(Url+pageNumber);
    request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    request.setMethod('GET');
    request.setTimeOut(60000);
    HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
    return response;
}
```

And logs problem pictures,

Attention: First request its worked, below the picture has second request

[image: DML END And Endpoint null]

Thanks from now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are mixing here the concept of `start` and `execute` methods of `Database.Batchable<sObject>` interface.

in `start`, you are writing a query, that defines what records should be processed in `execute` method. Just a filter for records that should be selected. In order to set size of records passed to `execute` method as a `scope`, use `Database.executeBatch(instance_of_batch, batch_size)` `batch_size` param.

so, you want to do the following changes:

```
Database.executeBatch(instance_of_batch, 10);
```

and change `start` in batch

```
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext info){
    return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Main_Stock__c,ProductCode From Product2]);
}
```

Comment: Hello firstly thanks for your answer but i have another problem thats why i couldnt use query locator, when i get response to api am getting product codes for the soql command, `[SELECT Main_Stock__c,ProductCode From Product2 Where ProductCode IN: keys.keySet()];` and am executing this soql command for the less process time, can i use this in query locator ? if i can use how i need the use,